# Does Office365 Compliance hold Outlook OWA ChatMessages?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

In Office365 (pure), if you setup an In-Place hold on an Exchange online mailbox you can do searches in Compliance Admin Centre for `kind:im` to get IM messages.

Such searches only return Skype for Business Online chats, apparently, not OWA IM's as per:

```
 0. open OWA app
 1. select a contact
 2. send an IM
```

Should this be working, or this just not supported?

(I'm using an E3 trial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a client only setting - where the SFB client saves the history back to Exchange/Outlook.

I just did some tests as well and they do not appear to get stored in the Exchange mailbox anywhere.  I could not find a definitive technet/MSDN mention of this, and I didn't find it in the service description, so I believe this is the case (they are not saved)